# Unable to create new "Release" pipeline in Azure DevOps Server (TFS) 2019

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

I am the part of the "Project Administrators" as well as "Project Teams". I have checked my permission in "Project settings/Security". Everything looks fine. However, the "Save" button in newly creating "Release Pipeline is disabled. I click on "..." for that pipeline and there too, the "Security" option is disabled. Which permission I am missing in Azure DevOps Server which will allow me to create "Release" pipeline?

Comment: Hi @user1748546, may i know if the reply below helps? let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions for Releases are defined at the folder level for the Release.

[image: Release Security]

There are a few [important permissions related](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#set-release-permissions) to editing Release Pipelines.

[image: Release Permissions]

- **Edit release pipeline**: Can save any changes to a release pipeline, including configuration variables, triggers, artifacts, and retention policy as well as configuration within a stage of the release pipeline. *To update a specific stage in a release pipeline, the user also needs Edit release stage permission.*

  Scopes: Project, Release pipeline
- **Edit release stage**: Can edit stage(s) in release pipeline(s). To save the changes to the release pipeline, the user also needs Edit release pipeline permission. This permission also controls whether a user can edit the configuration inside the stage of a *specific release instance*. The user also needs **Manage releases permission** to save the modified release.

  Scopes: Project, Release pipeline, Stage
- **Manage releases**: Can edit stage(s) in release pipeline(s). To save the changes to the release pipeline, the user also needs Edit release pipeline permission. This permission also controls whether a user can edit the configuration inside the stage of a specific release instance. The user also needs Manage releases permission to save the modified release.

  Scopes: Project, Release pipeline, Stage

The main difference between Edit Release and Manage Release: "Edit" refers to the ability to edit future instances of this release; "Manage" refers to the ability to edit a specific instance of a release after it's been queued.

Note that you can also set permissions on individual stages as well.

[image: Stage Permissions]

As to why you can't save? You have the **Edit release pipeline** permission because as you mentioned you have the option to create new Release pipelines. So by this definition, you should be able to save the Release (if it's valid).

New Release pipelines that haven't been saved will always have the Security option disabled, so this isn't an issue.

The editor will prevent you from saving if the pipeline is missing important details, which I suspect might be your issue.

[image: Save Disabled]

Answer (score 0):

> However, the "Save" button in newly creating "Release Pipeline is disabled. I click on "..." for that pipeline and there too, the "Security" option is disabled. Which permission I am missing in Azure DevOps Server which will allow me to create "Release" pipeline?

Since you are using ADO server 2019, project admin has the permission to create by default, it's mostly like **NOT** caused by the permission.

Please follow below items for a check:

1. Check if there's any warning(`red !`) in the release which will prevent you saving the release.

You can try to create a new simple release check if it works.

[image]

2. If the task is fine, check if someone else can setup the release in the project. If he/she can, remove your account from project and add back.
3. Disable some DevOps extension for a check.
4. Change the network if you have proxy set up on the machine.